# Using CSS in html vs html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

When I run my .html file there is no problem. There is a styled page. However; when I change .html file to .html.erb it doesn't import the scss file and I see a pure html page. Is there a special import method for .html.erb files? How can I fix this?

Comment: how are you including you css in your files ?

Comment: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/stylesheets/main.scss" />'

Comment: where is that files placed ?, is it in `/public` folder in your rails app ?. Perhaps it'd be better if you use rails helper `stylesheet_link_tag`, try: `stylesheet_link_tag('stylesheets/main.scss')` in case it's in your `assets` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some rules [rules](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) regarding how to easily manage assets.

Include the main stylesheet in your layout :

You'll have to precompile your stylesheet before. For example :

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['main.scss']
```